# DecimalFormat parsing invalid formatted string with no issue

Tags: java, parsing, decimalformat, formatted-input

```
System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("###,###.##").parse("123123.33"));

System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("###,###.##").parse("123,123.33"));
```

Both return the same value: `123123.33`.
However, in the first case, I need to validate and return with `fail`.

Comment: On what basis should the first one be failed?

Comment: "123123.33" is not in "###,###.##" format

Comment: To validate use regex, first one is giving correct response.

Comment: both "123123.33" and  "###,###.##"  are user inputs..  format is not fixed..

Comment: @AmanGarg These are not regular expressions, they are numeric format strings.

Comment: I was saying if you want to validate the format, then use regex.   Dateformat won’t help you..